# Symbolic interpolation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, interpolation

As the input data I have three arrays: X contains the x-coordinates, Y contains the y-coordinates and Z is the function of the first two coordinates, Z = f(X,Y).

The code is here:

```
X = [0 1 5 4 2 5 0 5 3];
Y = [0 3 2 6 6 1 2 12 2];
Z = [500 440 300 580 410 800 700 400 700];
```

I know the way to interpolate using these points. I used `griddata` and it was okay. But now I need to create a symbolic expression with MATLAB. I read about `polyfit` and `feval` but still don't really understand from what I should start and how to build an interpolational function z = f(x,y). Is there any way to make, for example, bicubic interpolation? 
As the output I wanna get a symbolic expression.

I would appreciate any help because I'm really interested in it

Comment: Why do you want a symbolic expression of an interpolation formula? It's a very strange thing to need.

Comment: @David yeah. I need a symbolic function. Like f(x_1, x_2).

Comment: You could do `f=@(x_1,x_2) interp2d(X,Y,Z,x_1,x_2)` to get the interpolated values, is that good enough? The symbolic expression would likely be far too complicated to do anything with.

Comment: @David I'd say it's better to use `griddata` as the data aren't monotonically increasing. No, I needed the symbolic expression). I know how to get the interpolated values))

Comment: OK. If `sims x1 x2` then `f(x1,x2)` doesn't work I think you'd have to code up the interpolation algorithm yourself, then get the value for a pair of symbolic inputs. I still can't believe you need a symbolic representation though!

Comment: @David Yeah, I thought of creating the interpolation code by myself, but hoped to find another ways haha

Comment: I need this too @David, in my case it's because I have a symbolic expression that requires the use of real world data and this data needs to be interpolated